# Colocar display none a los id que contengan una palabra de la cadena de texto

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Me explico, tengo base de datos a la que le he realizado una consulta sql sencilla en la que saco una columna.

```
SELECT fruta FROM fruteria;
```

Este select al recibirlo en mi documento lo he tranformado a json para poder trabajar con el en js de este modo:

```
<script>
var arrayToJs = <?php echo json_encode($category); ?>;
         console.log(arrayToJs);
         document.write(arrayToJs);
</script>
```

de forma que yo recibo el siguiente texto:

```
["manzana","pera","naranja","cereza","aguacate","platano"]
```

Tengo los siguientes divs

```
<div id="manzana"></div>
<div id="pera"></div>
<div id="naranja"></div>
<div id="cereza"></div>
<div id="aguacate"></div>
<div id="platano"></div>
```

Como puedo conseguir a través de js o jquery que cada vez que se encuentre la palabra que coincide con el id de ese div le pongo un display:none?

He probado lo siguiente:

```
//convertimos a json la cadena recibida
  let convertirJson = JSON.parse(arrayToJs);

  //extraemos todos sus elementos
  let extraerManzana = convertirJson[0];
  let extraerPera = convertirJson[1];
  let extraerNaranja = convertirJson[2];
  let extraerCereza = convertirJson[3];
  let extraerAguacate = convertirJson[4];
  let extraerPlatano = convertirJson[5];

//conseguimos los id de cada div
  let manzana = document.getElementById('manzana');
  let pera = document.getElementById('pera');
  let naranja = document.getElementById('naranja');
  let cereza = document.getElementById('cereza');
  let aguacate = document.getElementById('aguacate');
  let platano = document.getElementById('platano');

//comprueba si existe manzana y si es igual colocaria el display none
if(extraerManzana != null && extraerManzana == manzana){
    console.log('hola');
    manzana.style.display = "none";
}
```

Pero nunca saca el mensaje "hola", como compruebo que extraerManzana existe o no?

Que pasaria si de repente el valor de manzana no existe y aparece pera?
Como posicion [0] ?

Me explico en caso de no tener todos los campos llenos, sino que tenga por ejemplo solo pera y cereza en este caso pera seria la posicion[0] y cereza la posicion[1], como puedo realizar esta comparacion correctamente para que funcione bien ?

Comment: para obtener el nombre del id puedes usar getAttribute("id"), luego resta comparalo con los valores dentro del array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según lo que muestras en la pregunta, ya tienes un arreglo y no necesitas usar `JSON.parse()`:

```
<script>
var arrayToJs = <?php echo json_encode($category); ?>;
console.log(arrayToJs);
// Salida: ["manzana", "pera", "naranja", "cereza", "aguacate", "platano"]
</script>
```

Este otro fragmento de código no es útil:

```
//extraemos todos sus elementos
let extraerManzana = convertirJson[0];
let extraerPera = convertirJson[1];
let extraerNaranja = convertirJson[2];
let extraerCereza = convertirJson[3];
let extraerAguacate = convertirJson[4];
let extraerPlatano = convertirJson[5];
```

Imagina que "manzana" no es el primer elemento o ni siquiera existe en el arreglo, `extraerManzana` no necesariamente va a tener el valor deseado. En caso de que el arreglo contenga solo 4 elementos, tanto `extraerAguacate` como `extraerPlatano` van a generar error por índice no definido.

Si solo quieres ocultar los elementos que están en el arreglo, no necesitas obtener todos los `div`, solo recorrer el arreglo con [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) y ocultar cada uno por ID:

```js
// Voy a quitar algunos para que no se oculten todos y ver que funciona
let arrayToJs = ["manzana", "naranja", "aguacate"];

// Recorre el arreglo:
arrayToJs.forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none');
```

```html
<div id="manzana">Manzana</div>
<div id="pera">Pera</div>
<div id="naranja">Naranja</div>
<div id="cereza">Cereza</div>
<div id="aguacate">Aguacate</div>
<div id="platano">Plátano</div>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda.